# Eigen eulerAngles seems extrat wrong yaw

Tags: scipy, eigen

Eigen fuction cannot work as expected.

For the same rotation matrix, I used 3 methods to extract the RPY.
Rotation matrix:

-0.944488  0.328545        -0

-0.328545 -0.944488         0

0         0         1

For eigen,

```
    Eigen::Vector3d euler = rotationMatrix.eulerAngles(2, 1, 0);
    yaw = euler[0];
    pitch = euler[1];
    roll = euler[2];
```

output:yaw:19.1805

For python,

```
rotation_matrix = np.array([[-0.944488, 0.328545, -0],
                            [-0.328545, -0.944488, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1]])
r = R.from_matrix(rotation_matrix)
euler = r.as_euler('ZYX', degrees=True)
    yaw = euler[0];
    pitch = euler[1];
    roll = euler[2];
```

output:-160.81951023009094

And normal method,

```
  double yaw = std::atan2(R(1, 0), R(0, 0));
```

output:yaw:-160.82

Why that happened?Do something I missed?

Comment: Don't ask me why, probably different conventions, but `rotationMatrix.eulerAngles(0, 1, 2)` gives the expected result in `euler[2]`

Comment: There are (IIRC) 24 Euler angle conventions, which are not very obvious to distinguish. Maybe, the unsupported Euler module is more convienient for your use case: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1EulerAngles.html